# How to see current status of backup running of a database?

Tags: sql-server

I want to see the current status of backup running of a database which dmv can be used?

Example:

```
db1 is now 30% completed.
db1 is now 50% completed.
db1 is now 70% completed.
db1 is now 100% completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sys.dm_exec_requests + sys.dm_exec_sql_text

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/